# Error hanlder for FileStream - AS3 AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, filestream

I'm saving an object to a file using `FileStream`. The object I'm saving has variables in it:

```
var saveObj:Object = new Object()
saveObj['FirstName']="Georges"
saveObj['LastName']="St-Pierre"
```

MY question is this: How do I make an error handler for a variable missing when I load the File? For example 'Firstname' is missing. How do I do that? This is the code I have but it doesn't work.

```
private function F_loadData():void {
    folder = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("saved projects");
    var file:File = folder.resolvePath("mySave.adktf");
    var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    stream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler); 
    stream.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler); 
    stream.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorHandler); 
    stream.openAsync(file, FileMode.READ);
    var myLoadedObj:Object = stream.readObject(); 
    stream.close()
    trace(myLoadedObj.MiddleName)
}
private function completeHandler(event:Event):void { 
    trace("load Complete")//not final. Just for testing
} 

private function progressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void { 
    // ... 
} 
//I was hoping the error would call this function
private function errorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void { 
    trace("Error found")//not final. Just for testing
}
```

trace(myLoadedObj.MiddleName) should return an error and i was hoping that it would call the error Handler function that I made, but it didn't. It still returns an error. So how and what type of error handler should I use?

Comment: strange thing, you say your are saving the file but all your code does is reading it.

Comment: i already saved my file. My question was about error on loading data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are opening your file asynchronously, you need to wait to use `readObject` until after the complete event.

The error handler you've defined is only applicable to the loading of the file. SO if there is a problem opening the file the error handler will be called, any other kind of error is outside that scope.

Try something like this:

```
private var stream:FileStream;
private function F_loadData():void {
    folder = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("saved projects");
    var file:File = folder.resolvePath("mySave.adktf");

    if(file.exists){
        stream = new FileStream();
        stream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler); 
        stream.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler); 
        stream.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorHandler); 
        stream.openAsync(file, FileMode.READ);
        //now wait for it to load
    }else{
        //file doesn't exist, do something
    }
}
private function completeHandler(e:Event):void { 
    trace("load Complete")//not final. Just for testing

    var myLoadedObj:Object = stream.readObject(); 
    stream.close();
    stream = null;

    if(!myLoadedObj.MiddleName || myLoadedObj.MiddleName == ""){
        //Middle name is missing or empty, do something
    }

    if(!myLoadedObj.FirstName || myLoadedObj.FirstName == ""){
       //First name is missing or empty, do something
    }
}
```

---

You may be better suited to using a custom class for your save object, something like this:

```
package {
    public class SaveObject {
        public var middleName:String;
        public var lastName:String;
        //any other properties

        public function validate():Boolean {
            //write some validation

            //if you want lazy validation, you could do this: (untested)
            for (var i in obj){
                if(obj[i] is String && (obj[i] == null || obj[i] == "")){
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can do this: (in your constructor)

```
flash.net.registerClassAlias("SaveData",SaveData);
```

Then you can do the following:

```
var mySaveData:SaveData = new SaveData();
//set properties

stream.writeObject(mySaveData);


//then later
var mySaveData:SaveData = stream.readObject();

if(!mySaveData.validate()){
    //do something, it's invalid
}
```

Comment: i've thought about doing that but i have many variables in my object. My code is going to be long. I guess thats the only route i can take. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ive changed e.currentTarget to event.currentTarget because it doesnt match with completeHandler parameter. But still it doesnt work.. The reference to the Stream doesnt work. The error comes from this line 
    var myLoadedObj:Object = stream.readObject();

Comment: Can you explain to me what this code does in simple terms.
    flash.net.registerClassAlias("SaveData",SaveData);

Comment: It tells AS3 how to serialize and unserialize that class.  Without, when you write the object, it will be converted to a basic object.  When you read it back in, you can't easily then convert it to it's complex class (`SaveData`).  You need to register any class/sub classes you use that aren't primatives (eg String/Number/Int/Uint/Array are all fine without it)

Comment: Im able to save and load using Filestream.. How do i delete a file?

Comment: `file.deleteFile();`  You should really check the documentation as it shows all the various ways to work with files.

Comment: Sorry about that.. I looked at FileStream documentation instead of File Documentation... thanks anyway..